# How can I get the information entered into custom dialog in the fragment?

Tags: kotlin, dialog

I have the buttonStart that starts the OnClickLister event to launch the DialogCustom in the fragment.

**StartActivityFragment.kt**
[image]

In the DialogNewCounter (Custom dialog) I get the response from the editTextNameDialogNewCounter which I want to send it to the fragment, to pass the information I use the RequestDialog interface.

**dialog_new_counter.xml**
[image]

**DialogNewCounter.kt**
[image]

In the fragment (StarActivityFragment.kt of the first photo) I implement the Resquest Dialog interface and overwrite the onRequest method. Compiling it gives me the following error.

[image]
Someone who can help me please, I am several days with this problem. I would thank you a lot

Comment: hey I just posted my answer try it and let me know if you have any query.

Comment: @Fahed Hermoza, please follow [proper format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) when asking question, I think down votes are for using images instead of text for the code sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

Make two changes

**1. change the dialog show code.**

**From this:-**

```
val dialog = DialogNewCounter()
dialog.show(activity?.supportFragmentManager, "dialog_counter")
```

**To this:-**

```
val dialog = DialogNewCounter()
dialog.show(childFragmentManager, "dialog_counter")
```

**2. second change in `DialogNewCounter()` on button click**

**From this:-**

```
(activity as RequestDialog).onRequest(result)
```

**To this:-**

```
(parentFragment as RequestDialog?)!!.onRequest(result)
```